# Проблема с сортировкой множественного списка

Tags: python

Пытаюсь отсортировать ряд во множественном списке , а на выходе получаю None . Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема .

```
ink = [
    [5, 8, 1, 7, 9, 2],
    [5, 4, 1, 8, 9, 2],
    [5, 8, 6, 3, 0, 2],
]
print(ink[1].sort())
```

Comment: А что не так? list.sort() ничего не возвращает

Comment: Он возвращает None

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `.sort()` работает прямо с **оригинальным** списком, изменяя его на месте.

В Питоне принято, что такие методы возвращают `None`, что вы и получили.

Вы можете или

- **сначала** сортировать, **затем** выводить (измененный) оригинальный список:

  ```
   ink[1].sort()
   print(ink[1])
  ```

или

- применить **функцию** `sorted()` с вашим списком между скобками:

  ```
   print(sorted(ink[1]))
  ```

  т.к. функция `sorted()` возвращает новый, упорядоченный список, не меняя оригинальный.

Comment: А если я захочу отсортировать не ряд а столбик . Как отсортировать в таком случае ?

Comment: @andrew, нужно задать новый вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

Метод `.sort()` сортирует список *inplace*, то есть он ничего не возвращает (если быть точным - возвращает *None*), а отсортированный список занимает место старого. Чтобы посмотреть результат, надо так:

```
ink = [
    [5, 8, 1, 7, 9, 2],
    [5, 4, 1, 8, 9, 2],
    [5, 8, 6, 3, 0, 2],
]
ink[1].sort()
print(ink[1])
```

или так:

```
ink = [
    [5, 8, 1, 7, 9, 2],
    [5, 4, 1, 8, 9, 2],
    [5, 8, 6, 3, 0, 2],
]
print(sorted(ink[1]))
```

но в последнем случае, отсортированный список нигде не будет сохранен.

**UPD**

Я добавлю ответ на вопрос из комментария - что делать если сортировать надо не *строки*, а *столбцы*. На мой взгляд, самый простой способ это использовать `numpy`, так как базовый питон воспринимает исходный объект как список списков, а `numpy` - как двумерный массив, у которого есть и строки и столбцы.

```
import numpy as np

ink = [
    [5, 8, 1, 7, 9, 2],
    [5, 4, 1, 8, 9, 2],
    [5, 8, 6, 3, 0, 2],
]
# конвертируем список списков в массив numpy
ink_np = np.array(ink)

# сортируем какой-то столбец (например, по индексу 1)
ink_np[:, 1].sort()

# если есть необходимость, конвертируем обратно в список списков
ink = ink_np.tolist()
print(ink)
```

Comment: А если мне нужно отсортировать к примеру 2 столбик (8, 4 ,8) . Как это сделать ?

Comment: @andrew если допускается применение сторонних библиотек, то можно использовать numpy.

Comment: @andrew в ответе написал как сортировать столбец.